# How to subtract 1 from my final search result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

What I'm trying to do is when the search happens it filters the images by name but the problem is to make whole things disappear on filter i added

```
<ul id="list2"> 
          <li class="in2">
```

It adds 1 extra number to the result for example i have a 8 images but it shows 9 or when I search something and if there are 2 result it shows 3. So how can i subtract 1 from the search result ?

Here's my code

```
<ul id="list2">
      <div class="chartGap">  
          <li class="in2">
                <button class="customAccordion chartBackGroundColor">
                      <p class="chartTitle">Limestone</p>
                      <p class="chartViewAll">View All
                       <span class="list-count2"></span>
                            <svg class="chartIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                                  class="bi bi-arrow-down-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                  <path
                                        d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5.793l2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 10.293V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" />
                            </svg>
                      </p>
                </button>
                <div class="panel">




<main class="chartMain">
      <div class="chartContainer">


    <li class="in2"> <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
            <a loading="eager"
                href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/OMNIAR_BEIGE_-_ROULLATO_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391209"
                data-fancybox="gallery-omniar-beige-roullato-limestone" data-caption="OMNIAR BEIGE ROULLATO LIMESTONE">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/OMNIAR_BEIGE_-_ROULLATO_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391209"
                    alt="OMNIAR BEIGE ROULLATO LIMESTONE">
            </a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="galleryCustomH">OMNIAR BEIGE <br> ROULLATO <br> LIMESTONE</h1>
    </div> </li>
    
    
    
    <li class="in2"> <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
            <a loading="eager"
                href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/OMNIAR_BEIGE_-_HONED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391209"
                data-fancybox="gallery-omniar-beige-honed-limestone" data-caption="OMNIAR BEIGE HONED LIMESTONE">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/OMNIAR_BEIGE_-_HONED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391209"
                    alt="OMNIAR BEIGE HONED LIMESTONE">
            </a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="galleryCustomH">OMNIAR BEIGE <br> HONED <br> LIMESTONE</h1>
    </div> </li>
    
    
    
    
    
    <li class="in2"> <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
            <a loading="eager"
                href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/GRISH_BHOPAL_LIGHT_-_HONED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391209"
                data-fancybox="gallery-grish-bhopal-light-honed-limestone"
                data-caption="GRISH BHOPAL LIGHT HONED LIMESTONE">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/GRISH_BHOPAL_LIGHT_-_HONED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391209"
                    alt="GRISH BHOPAL LIGHT HONED LIMESTONE">
            </a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="galleryCustomH">GRISH BHOPAL <br> LIGHT HONED <br> LIMESTONE</h1>
    </div> </li>
    
    
    
    <li class="in2"> <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
            <a loading="eager"
                href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/BLUE_BAT_-_HONED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391209"
                data-fancybox="gallery-blue-bat-honed-limestone" data-caption="BLUE BAT HONED LIMESTONE">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/BLUE_BAT_-_HONED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391209"
                    alt="BLUE BAT HONED LIMESTONE">
            </a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="galleryCustomH">BLUE BAT <br> HONED <br> LIMESTONE</h1>
    </div> </li>
    
    
    <li class="in2"> <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
            <a loading="eager"
                href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/BEIGE_MODEON_-_POLISHED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391209"
                data-fancybox="gallery-beige-modeon-polished-limestone" data-caption="BEIGE MODEON POLISHED LIMESTONE">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/BEIGE_MODEON_-_POLISHED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391209"
                    alt="BEIGE MODEON POLISHED LIMESTONE">
            </a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="galleryCustomH">BEIGE MODEON <br> POLISHED <br> LIMESTONE</h1>
    </div> </li>
    
    
    
    
    <li class="in2"> <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
            <a loading="eager"
                href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/AZUL_VALVERDE_-_POLISHED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391209"
                data-fancybox="gallery-azul-valverde-polished-limestone" data-caption="AZUL VALVERDE POLISHED LIMESTONE">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/AZUL_VALVERDE_-_POLISHED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391209"
                    alt="AZUL VALVERDE POLISHED LIMESTONE">
            </a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="galleryCustomH">AZUL VALVERDE <br> POLISHED <br> LIMESTONE</h1>
    </div> </li>
    
    
    
    <li class="in2"> <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
            <a loading="eager"
                href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/BLUE_VAL_-_HONED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391208"
                data-fancybox="gallery-blue-val-honed-limestone" data-caption="BLUE VAL HONED LIMESTONE">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/BLUE_VAL_-_HONED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391208"
                    alt="BLUE VAL HONED LIMESTONE">
            </a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="galleryCustomH">BLUE VAL <br> HONED <br> LIMESTONE</h1>
    </div> </li>
    
    
    <li class="in2"> <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
            <a loading="eager"
                href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/APOH_GREY_2_-_HONED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391208"
                data-fancybox="gallery-apoh-grey-2-honed-limestone" data-caption="APOH GREY 2 HONED LIMESTONE">
                <img
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0098/8318/9314/files/APOH_GREY_2_-_HONED_-_LIMESTONE_result.jpg?v=1669391208"
                    alt="APOH GREY 2 HONED LIMESTONE">
            </a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="galleryCustomH">APOH GREY 2 <br> HONED <br> LIMESTONE</h1>
    </div> </li>
    

      </div>
    </main>


                </div>
                </div>
          </li>
    </ul>





<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      
        var jobCount = $('#list2 .in2').length;
        $('.list-count2').text(jobCount + ' items');
          
        
        $("#search-text").keyup(function () {
           //$(this).addClass('hidden');
        
          var searchTerm = $("#search-text").val();
          var listItem = $('#list2').children('li');
        
          
          var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")
          
            //extends :contains to be case insensitive
        $.extend($.expr[':'], {
        'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array)
        {
          return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
          .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
        }
      });
          
          
          $("#list2 li").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e)   {
            $(this).addClass('hiding out').removeClass('in2');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.out').addClass('hidden');
              }, 300);
          });
          
          $("#list2 li:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
            $(this).removeClass('hidden out').addClass('in2');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.in2').removeClass('hiding');
              }, 1);
          });
          
        
            var jobCount = $('#list2 .in2').length;
          $('.list-count2').text(jobCount + ' items');
          
          //shows empty state text when no jobs found
          if(jobCount == '0') {
            $('#list2').addClass('empty');
          }
          else {
            $('#list2').removeClass('empty');
          }
          
        });
      });
      
      </script>
```

Comment: Your html <ul id="list2">
      <div class="chartGap">  
          <li class="in2"> is malfarmed also first li is missing closing tag correct your code and then count list

Comment: Yes, please use a good editor or an HTML validator. Paragraphs have no business inside buttons. Divs are not valid children of lists. List items must be children of lists. It's very difficult to work with a poorly-constructed document. Since it needs so much repair we can't really give good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an solution

```
var jobCount = $('#list2 .in2').length - 1;
```